# Retrieving data from a phone stuck in a bootloop due to running out of memory

Tags: android, adb, xiaomi, fastboot

As I dont know anything about android fixing I need help on the steps to get to a solution

My phone (xiaomi redmi note 9 pro eea) recently got into a boot loop because it´s memory got completely full, now I'm looking for a way to fix it and get my data or get my data right away.

I got it to a repair shop to be sure the boot loop wasn't fault of the power button and they confirmed it.

The phone hasn't root unlocked, a custom rom, the oem unlocking option activated but I think it has the usb debugging activated.

The solutions I think could work are

- getting the data with adb fastboot or a program like mipcsuite
- deleting any file, app or cache with adb, fastboot or other tool to free space
- flashing a rom like twrp if it helps to backup data or flash other rom that uses less space

I don't really now if any of these solutions could work because as I mentioned before the phone hasn't root unlocked, a custom rom, the oem unlocking option activated but could have usb debugging activated.